# Use View or Fragment in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a question about whether to use View or Fragment with ViewPager.

Background:
    I have an Activity A that contains a ListView. Each ListView item opens Activity B. Activity B shows different content depending on which ListView item is tapped in Activity A.
Activity B's content is shown inside a ListView.

Question:
Now, instead of going back and forth between Activity A and B to switch contents, I have a requirement to implement horizontal view swiping to switch contents all within Activity B.
One solution I found (tried it and it works) is to create many instances of Activity B's ListView and use it with ViewPager + PagerAdapter.
Another potential solution found on the doc (haven't tried it) is to bring that ListView into a Fragment, create many instances of the fragment and use it with ViewPager + FragmentPagerAdapter or FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

My question is, what's the benefit of using each approach? Should I go through all the trouble of bringing the ListView into Fragment or just simply use ListView with ViewPager?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `Fragment` is a useful approach, I think, when you want to tie some UI business logic to a particular `View` (or group of). As you know, that individual `Fragment` has its own lifecycle callbacks and so forth, just as an `Activity` would.

Rather than having a single `Activity` host many `ListView`s through a single `PagerAdapter`, it *may* be cleaner to use the `Fragment` approach because the `Fragment` only needs to deal with the logic behind driving a single `ListView`.

This is a very similar situation to one I've just been facing. I'm showing various vertically scrolling forms (consisting of lots of input fields) within a `ViewPager`. In my case I have gone for the `Fragment` approach because in my case, it's possible that the `ViewPager` will actually need to display a completely different kind of view on certain pages. For example, on the first few pages, user input forms might be displayed. But on the final page, a graph will be displayed. A whole separate set of logic is required to drive that graph. To drive those input forms and one graph from a single `Activity` would get a bit messy, and I would probably need to contain the business logic in several delegate classes or something. So for me, `Fragment`s were the obvious choice in the end. I have my `InputFormFragment` and a `GraphFragment`, and they each contain only the applicable logic for the `View`s that they supply.

Another thing to consider is that in the near future you too may want to display a different kind of `View` in your `ViewPager`. Or, you might want to have another UI layout altogether, perhaps one that doesn't use the `ViewPager` but displays them all side-to-side (e.g. a layout used on a large tablet in landscape mode). With `Fragment`s, things are just far more modular and you could factor the code to do this quicker. If on the other hand you achieved your objective by using a single `Activity` that contains a simple `PagerAdapter` and all the logic for the `ListView`s within, you might find it takes more work in the future to support new kinds of `View`s or special tablet layouts.

One thing I will say is having implemented `Fragment`s in a `ViewPager` myself through `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, things can get a bit awkward if you have any special requirements; managing `Fragment`s can be tricky sometimes. For example, for my UI I needed to be able to programmatically add and remove the `ViewPager` containing the `Fragment`s. I also needed to ensure that the adapter in use didn't destroy `Fragment`s once they had been shown, because I needed to collect data from all `Fragment`s simultaneously at a certain point. Furthermore, I had to extend and modify `FragmentPagerAdatper` to make sure that the `Fragment`s go through their `onDestroy()` properly and are removed from the `FragmentManager` when the `ViewPager` was removed.

`Fragment`s enable a very modular way of constructing UIs for various screen sizes and orientations, and are excellent in how they allow you to encapsulate business logic and lifecycles for individual UI elements. However if your scenario really is just as simple as several `ListView`s in a `ViewPager` and you know that you will never need the modularity, then the overhead of `Fragment`s could be an overkill.

Comment: About collecting info from fragments, wouldn't it be easier to create an interface, have the fragment host a reference to an object that implements it and use the interface functions to store the info in that object?

Comment: If I understand right, I think what you're suggesting is that instead of needing to do clever things to ensure all Fragments stay around in the ViewPager (and aren't constantly killed and then created again), I should instead have a mechanism to persist their state. I could have done this and I'd agree that'd be a better approach, but the Fragments in my particular application are quite expensive to construct. For both coding and performance reasons, it was more straightforward to just ensure all Fragments stay around, and then request that they all submit their data together.