# Cannot retrieve the correct TextView by using findViewById inside of two different Fragments based on a single layout.xml file

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I'm using a `FragmentPagerAdapter` in the `MainActivity`. I use `res\layout\fragment_text.xml` file to create two fragments each with different data entered by the user. When I try to `findViewById()`, It returns data from a different fragment. Here is the applicable code:

```
    //this is from my public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        switch (position){
            case 0:  return MultipleChoiceSingleAnswerFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            **case 1:  return TextFragment.newInstance("1", "2");**
            **case 2:  return TextFragment.newInstance("10", "20");**
            case 3:  return ScoreFragment.newInstance("100", "200");
            default: return null;
        }
    }

 //here I collect the fragment tags as they are being instantiated

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment newFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        // save the appropriate fragment tag depending on position
        fragmentTags[position] = newFragment.getTag();//store in array of Strings
        return newFragment;
    }
```

In an `onclick` listener I try to retrieve the fragment and show text that the user entered, into an `EditText` view, using a toast. This code is called in another Fragment that has just a `TextView` and a Button

```
public void onScorePressed(){
       int pageCount = mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount();
    **TextFragment textfragment = (TextFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTags[1]);
    CharSequence text = textfragment.getAnswer()**;<<<<<main problem in call,see below
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();

}
```

In line above `textfragment.getAnswer()' calls this method which exists in two instances of the same fragment class:

```
public class TextFragment extends Fragment {
    //other code for building a Fragment
 .....
//This method return text entered by user as well as the mParam1 used in the instantiation above in Fragment getItem case 1:; 
public CharSequence getAnswer(){
    EditText txt = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.text_answer);
    return "mParam1=" + mParam1 + "text_answer=" + txt.getText();
}
```

The *getAnswer* method returns

> "mParam1=1 text_answer=*text entered*"

from the second TextFragment instantiated in *case 2* above. This shows that I'm actually getting the correct TextFragment because mParam1 matches the parameter passed in the instantiation. I need a better way to get the EditText View's text. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.
Posts I used in my research:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12805033/9226205
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html

Comment: No need to use `getFragmentByTag()`, just keep references to the fragments that you get in the `instantiateItem()` override.

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. I do not get a null pointer exception. I get a fragment back but its the wrong one. My code uses 1 layout.xml file to create two pages/fragments with the same layout but different data. I can only retrieve the second instance no matter which tag I use.

Comment: I just tried the method mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503779/refresh-data-in-viewpager-fragment
but I still get thee same results. Both fragments have the data from the second one instantiated.

Comment: Show your `newInstance()` method in TextFragment.  It looks like maybe you're only creating one instance of TextFragment, when you should have multiple instances.

Comment: @DanielNugent I have two fragments for sure as I can change the index to get the second one. newInstance() only creates one fragment but it is called twice.  
    `public static TextFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        TextFragment fragment = new TextFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have tags set for your fragments and that's why you can't retrieve the fragments by tag. As far as I know, fragment tag can only be set in the XML layout or when the fragment is created using transaction's add or replace methods. I would expect a NullPointerExeption in

```
fragmentTags[position] = newFragment.getTag();
```

since the tag was not previously set.

As a solution, I suggest an array that holds references to your fragments, instead of an array of tags:

```
Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[NUMBER_OF_FRAGMENTS];
```

So **getItem** method could look like this:

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
       Fragment fragment;    
       switch (position){
          case 0:  
            fragment = MultipleChoiceSingleAnswerFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            break;
          case 1:  
            fragment = TextFragment.newInstance("1", "2");
            break;
          case 2:  
            fragment = TextFragment.newInstance("10", "20");
            break;
          case 3:  
            fragment = ScoreFragment.newInstance("100", "200");
          default: 
            fragment = null;
      }
      fragments[position]=fragment;
      return fragment;
    }
```

Then you can completely omit **instantiateItem** method because it is not needed.

Finally, in **onScorePressed** method you get the reference to the right fragment by

```
TextFragment textfragment = fragments[i];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please see my edits. I am getting the correct Fragment. The problem is when I try to get text from EditText view by using getViewById. Also, I did what you suggested but still have the same issue as mentioned. Thanks for your input. Please review my post again if you have time.

Comment: If you just need the text from the EditText, why don't you just return txt.getText() instead of "mParam1=" + mParam1 + "text_answer=" + txt.getText() ?

Comment: Returning the mParam was just a debugging technique. It showed that my problem was not with getFragmentByTag but with the getting of the text in the fragment by using getViewById. At least that's what I thought. It started working today and I can't say why. Thanks for your input.